# Difference between alert and navigator.notification.alert in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

**What is the difference between `alert` and `navigator.notification.alert` in PhoneGap?**

*Or In other words*

**Why should i use navigator.notification.alert instead of simple alert?**

[Official docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert) says that `navigator.notification.alert` should be used for more flexibility.

I just want to know that is it just because the extent of flexibility that they recommend to use `navigator.notification.alert` or there are some other issues too with simple alert?

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.notification.alert` provides more modification flexibility, e.g.

- change button text
- alert callback

Reference: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

Comment: I already know what you have mentioned in your answer. Infact, the link you have added is already their in question. My question is different. BTW, thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I intentionally added the link you quoted. Suggest to use `navigator.notification.alert` as PhoneGap has done things for cross-platform sake.

Comment: do you want to say that "simple alert is not working properly on different platforms and so we should use `navigator.notification.alert`?"

Comment: Maybe, simple alert is not guaranteed to work on cross-platform. If PhoneGap offers an API for alert and said proven for cross-platform, why don't you pick that ?